# Having Log filenames with "AnyName"_yyy-MM-dd.log in log4net

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

### How It already does work

I have already been using log4net for a while now, usually my Configuration looks lomehow like that:

```
        Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
        hierarchy.Configured = true;

        _roller = new RollingFileAppender();
        _patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
        _roller.Layout = _patternLayout;


        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(_roller);


        hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Info
        _roller.AppendToFile = true;
        _roller.File = Path.Combine(FileDirectory, ".log");
        _roller.StaticLogFileName = false;
        _roller.PreserveLogFileNameExtension = true;
        _roller.LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock();
        _roller.MaxSizeRollBackups = -1; //--> Logger doesn't delete files himself
        _roller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Composite;
        _roller.MaximumFileSize = LogFileSize;
        _roller.DatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        _roller.PreserveLogFileNameExtension = true;

        _patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date [%-5level] %message%newline";
        _patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

        _roller.ActivateOptions();
```

I do configure the log4net component via c# code, because i need to have it dynamic.

*The Files generated, look like that:*

- yyyy-MM-dd.log
- yyyy-MM-dd.Count.log

### My Question

*Now my Logfiles should be named like that:*

- OPCReaderClient_yyyy-MM-dd.log
- OPCReaderClient_yyyy-MM-dd.Count.log

Thats why I made the following changes to my configuration

```
        _roller.DatePattern = "OPCReaderClient_yyyy-MM-dd";
```

But the Result is the following:
*OPCRea19erClienA_2015-08-19.log*

## WHY?

The point is, that I want the Prefix to be dynamic. So i need to know how I can achieve that any of my Logfiles will be named correctly as long as the prefix only contains ASCII Characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`d` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dSpecifier) in Rea**d**er represents single day format specifier and [`t` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#tSpecifier) in Clien**t** represents one character AM/PM designator. If you don't escape them, they behave as custom date and time format strings.

And [other characters are copied from the result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#escape).

You can escape them if you want as;

```
_roller.DatePattern = "OPCRea'd'erClien't'_yyyy-MM-dd";
```

Comment: So this does also work: `"'" + Prefix + "'_yyyy-MM-dd"` ?

Comment: @LuckyLikey Yes, If you don't escape them, they will behave as custom date and time format strings. You can escape all prefix string as well like you did.

Comment: It works as expected thank you. Will accept your answer ASAP